# Autocomplete python in vscode remote container

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I'm using the vscode extension importmagic which works fine when not working in a remote container. In the remote container I don't see my own classes and functions as suggestions for autocomplete.

I've tried adding

```
        "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
            "${workspaceFolder}",
        ],
```

to the settings in `devcontainer.json` where `workspaceFolder=/app`. If I set it to `${workspaceFolder}/module` it gives me suggestions for the underlying modules.

For example I have a structure like `module/sub_module/sub_sub_module` and it will suggest and add import automatically like `from sub_module.sub_sub_module import ...` but `module` is not included in the import so the import can't be resolved.

Is there a setting that I'm missing or why can't it detect underlying module when using only workspaceFolder as extraPaths?

Answer (score 6):

Change the Python-Server in settings.json
from "Pylance" or "Microsoft" or whatever you are using- to "Jedi"

```
"python.languageServer": "Jedi"
```

To be honest, no solutions worked for me except this one.

One of the solution is keep adding all the paths to extraPaths which doesn't sound good.
Instead use "Jedi" server. No need to add any extraPaths, it uses the directory of open files and folders for autocomplete and analysis by default.

Comment: Thanks, @hexr this helped me to find a solution. I set it to "Jedi" and I'd rebuilt my dev container.  A warning message showed up "IntelliCode Python support requires you to use the Microsoft Python Language Server." I clicked the button "Enable it and Reload Window". It changed it from "Jedi" to "Microsoft" and voila. I also tried adding a line to my Dockerfile "RUN pip install jedi" and reset the settings.json to use Jedi but nothing. I guess this is somehow related to the Python VS Code extension I'm using. Its provided by Microsoft. But, now it's working for me so I left on MS.

Answer (score 4):

You need to make sure that the extensions installed locally in vscode are also installed in the remote container. In your case the `Python` extension that allows the autocomplete features and many others are not installed.

Try to access to `Preferences/Extensions` and install them manually.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure VSCode is using the Python Interpreter from the container (instead of your local). You can do that in VSCode by typing `cmd + p` -> `Python: Select Interpreter` -> Select the version from the container.

Answer (score 0):

For Me it Worked to click on the left side to the Extensions and scroll down to Pylance. There is a button with "On: SSH: XXX. ... install". After the Install everything works fine.